Flutter how to login with Facebook Authentication with Firebase?
I'm using Firebase Authentication with Facebook Auth I installed this package
flutter_facebook_auth: ^6.2.0
and that's my code
final LoginResult loginResult = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();
      if (loginResult.status == LoginStatus.success) {
        final OAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential =
            FacebookAuthProvider.credential(loginResult.accessToken!.token);

        // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
        UserCredential userauth =
            await _auth.signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);
}

and that's my manifest file
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>

My login function is working fine with my personal Facebook account, but when I try to log in with a different Facebook account I get an error in the attached Image
How to solve this, please?
and that's my standard access

